# Undo apt-get install with many dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I tried "apt-get install sagemath" and it started downloading a lot of dependencies. I quickly ran out of disk-space and I interrupted the process.
I am now at 300mb of root space left and need to somehow undo the installation.
When i try to apt-get purge sagemath I get the following error
"E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem."

Now when I try to run that, my remaining disk space gets depleted. I don't know how to undo my mistake at this point, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt remove texlive-latex-base   
sudo apt remove maxima-sage maxima-sage-doc maxima-sage-share  
sudo apt remove octave  
sudo apt remove r-base-core  
sudo apt remove python-sympy python-scipy  
sudo apt remove python-flask python-flask-autoindex python-flask-babel python-flask-oldsessions python-flask-openid python-flask-silk    
sudo apt remove sagemath-database-conway-polynomials sagemath-database-elliptic-curves sagemath-database-graphs sagemath-database-mutually-combinatorial-designs sagemath-database-polytopes sagemath-doc-en sagemath-jupyter sagetex  
sudo apt remove sagemath # maybe you'll also have to run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Hey. I had to run the configure command before everything else. Nothing bad happend. And using autoremove to remove 350 packages was very satisfiying. Thanks!